# Remove ticks from chart labels

Tags: labeling, charts

Given the following chart:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, ChartLabels -> {{"r1", "r2"}, None}]
```

How can I remove the ticks of the chart labels (marked with red circles)?[image]

Comment: You can add the options `TicksStyle -> Opacity@0, LabelStyle -> Opacity@1` to make the ticks transparent, while keeping the labels visible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can post-process to remove the tick lines on the horizontal axis:

```
bc = BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, ChartLabels -> {{"r1", "r2"}, None}];
DeleteCases[bc, _Line?(Not@*FreeQ[_Offset]), All]
```

[image]

**Note:** Although the default settings for the horizontal axis are `False` for `Axes` and `{}` for `Ticks`,

```
Options[bc, Axes]
```

> {Axes -> {False, True}}

```
Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[bc, Ticks]// First
```

> {}

Lukas's suggestion  `TicksStyle -> {Opacity@0, Automatic}` and `LabelStyle -> Opacity[1]` also works.

Comment: That works well, thank you both for the help!